# AngularJS: $first + alter attribute in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A directive takes this code:

```
  <div ng-repeat="image in home_images | limitTo: 5 " imagesrc="img/links/{{image.file_name}}" imagelink="{{image.url}}" title="{{image.title}}" caption="{{image.caption}}" isbig="$first"></div>
```

(ng-class="{big: $first}" fails unexplicably here).

and should turns it into this:

```
<a ng-href="{{imagelink}}" class="image-link">
    <div class="image" ng-class="{big: isbig === 'true'}">
        <div class="caption"><h6>{{title}}</h6><span>{{caption}}</span></div>
        <img ng-src="{{imagesrc}}" alt="title">
    </div>
</a>
```

This is the directive:

```
  .directive('imagelink', function(){
    return {
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        imagesrc: '@',
        imagelink: '@',
        title: '@',
        caption: '@',
        isbig: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: 'partials/image-link.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          element.addClass('show-caption');
        });
        element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
          element.removeClass('show-caption');
        });
        if (attrs.isbig) {
          console.log(attrs);
          attrs.imagesrc = attrs.imagesrc + "_bg.png";
        } else {
          attrs.imagesrc = attrs.imagesrc + "_sm.png";
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

There are three problems:

- Attrs seems to update in the link function in the directive, but the update does not reflect in the view
- $first seems not to work (and why doesnt' ng-class="{big: $first}" work anyway?)
- isBig (that I use to go around the issue with $first) seems to be true or false for all the repetitions, defeating the purpose. This should never happen as $first is called outside the directive, and it shoud therefore update with each call to the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a jsfiddle or plunkr for such questions. It makes it much easier to help you. Your problem is actually because ng-repeat takes place after the template is inserted into the html code. Therefore it can not work like this. Make these changes:

In scope:

```
isbig: '='
```

This creates a two-way binding between isbig in the directive scope and the parent scope. This is necessary because, as said, ng-repeat is executed after template extraction. Therefore you need to have the isbig binded this way.

And then get rid of the attrs manipulation and instead add the necessary suffix in the template:

```
<img ng-src="{{imagesrc}}{{ (isbig&&'_bg.png'||'_sm.png') }}" alt="title">
```

For the ng-class issue. I can not get it working with that syntax. But this seems to work:

```
<div class="image {{isbig&&'big'||''}}">
```

So not using ng-class here, but my understanding of how angular will handle the repeat and stuff I believe there is no downside in that.

Oh, and here is a complete jsfiddle showing this: http://jsfiddle.net/hssPn/3/

Comment: This works perfectly. I am suprised not to have stumbled upon this syntax before on my own. Thanks!